# Is HashTable/HashMap an array?

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, hashtable

I am having confusion in hashing:

When we use Hashtable/HashMap (key,value), first I understood the internal data structure is an array (already allocated in memory).

Java hashcode() method has an int return type, so I think this hash value will be used as an index for the array and in this case, we should have 2 power 32 entries in the array in RAM, which is not what actually happens.

So does Java create an index from the hashcode() which is smaller range?

**Answer:**

As the guys pointed out below and from the documentation: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java

HashMap is an array. The hashcode() is rehashed again but still integer and the index in the array becomes: h & (length-1); so if the length of the array is 2^n then I think the index takes the first n bit from re-hashed value.

Comment: The standard Java API does not have a `HashTable` type. Did you mean `Hashtable`?

Comment: @LewBloch yes Hashtable

Comment: "In java hashcode() method has an int return type, so in theory we should have 2 power 32 (i.e. 4 Giga entries) already reserved for the array in RAM" - I don't see your reasoning here.

Comment: @JonSkeet Hi. Pls check the update above.

Comment: The update doesn't explain why you thought that the internal array would have to be size 2^32 in the first place. Your "so in theory" suggests a logical step that you haven't explained (and which is incorrect).

Comment: @JonSkeet because I thought, as mentioned in the post, that hashcode() return value will be used as it is for indexing in the array, so 2^32 entries. However there are some intermediate steps for indexing that reduces that range up to the user-specified/default length value of the array.

Comment: No, you didn't mention that at all. Your update shows what actually happens, but you never stated your earlier assumption that the hash code would be used directly.

Comment: @JonSkeet My friend, I said from the beginning "I am having confusion in hashing" so if every think was clear to me, why I asked so!. Further, I mentioned "in theory" which does not mean "in practice".  Anyway the purpose of the question is to find an answer so let's focus on the answer.

Comment: Yes, you said you were confused - but you didn't show your reasoning. My point is that you skipped the part of your reasoning that was flawed - which means we can't point out the flaw in the reasoning. If you explain *why* you think something should happen, we can point out which part was wrong. There may be several steps to that reasoning, with only one part being flawed. The more information you give about how you came to a given conclusion, the easier it is to help identify the specific problem.

Comment: It's like I tell my sons about their maths homework - if you just write down what you think the answer is, but it's wrong, we can't tell *why* it's wrong. If you write down each step you took to get to that answer, we can see which of those steps has a problem. Additionally, writing out your assumptions can often highlight to *you* where they're incorrect.

Comment: @JonSkeet that's completely true. But there is no perfect question and there is no perfect answer. what you didn't get, others might get and vice versa. There are already 4 people who answered me what I want, without asking me about that. And again if I new that there are intermediate steps between hashing and indexing I will not ask the question from the beginning. if you read the question again you can conclude that I am asking about this exactly "So does Java re-hashes the hashcode() value again into smaller one like byte/short?"

Comment: "But there is no perfect question and there is no perfect answer." That's no excuse not to at least *try* to write as clear a question as you can. You've still not edited it to clarify the question - you claimed that you'd written "I thought that hashcode() return value will be used as it is for indexing in the array". If you'd *actually* included that in the question to start with, it would have been much, much clearer. So edit the question now. The presence of answers *guessing* at your reasoning is no substitute for a clear *statement* of your reasoning.

Comment: @JonSkeet "You've still not edited it to clarify the question" by the way I edited the question several times to make it clearer but again "there is no perfect question" because it is related to the answer?

Comment: I give up at this stage. I've explicitly said (speaking from considerable experience of reading, asking and answering a *lot* of Stack Overflow questions) how you could make the question significantly better, but if you choose to ignore that, you can do so of course. You should be aware that better questions generally attract better answers and upvotes. I suggest you read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/. This will be my final comment here.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am not ignoring that, but I am clarifying my point that I didn't know the answer so my question might not be perfect. And it seems you want me to modify the question after getting the answer and that is what you should tell me from the beginning. Now I think the question is better you can take a look.

Comment: @JonSkeet if you still have comments on the phrasing of the question you can tell, for me it seems good like this.

Answer (score 2):

The structure for a Java `HashMap` is not just an array. It is an array, but not of `2^31` entries (`int` is a signed type!), but of some smaller number of buckets, by default `16` initially. The Javadocs for `HashMap` explain that.

When the number of entries exceeds a certain fraction (the "load factor) of the capacity, the array grows to a larger size.

Each element of the array does not hold only one entry. Each element of the array holds a structure (currently a red-black tree, formerly a list) of entries. Each entry of the structure has a hash code that transforms internally to the same bucket position in the array.

Have you read the docs on this type?
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

You really should.

Comment: Thanks Lew. So in case the HashMap used number of buckets less than 2^31 that means the int hash value returned from hashcode() method will be re-hashed  again to fit the range e.g. 16 by default, please correct me if I am wrong? If this is the case what is the currently used way/algorithm for re-hashing that int hash value into smaller one(is it the simple modulo )?

Comment: @MosabShaheen Why don't you just read the documentation and source code of HashMap? It's free, and bundled with your JDK.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks. The hashcode() is rehashed again but still int and the index in the array becomes: h & (length-1); so if the length of the array is 2^n then I think the index takes the first n bit from re-hashed value.
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java

Comment: This seams reasonable, Lew +1

Answer (score 1):

Generally the base data structure will indeed be an array.

The methods that need to find an entry (or empty gap in the case of adding a new object) will reduce the hash code to something that fits the size of the array (generally by modulo), and use this as an index into that array.

Of course this makes the chance of collisions more likely, since many objects could have a hash code that reduces to the same index (possible anyway since multiple objects might have exactly the same hash code, but now much more likely). There are different strategies for dealing with this, generally either by using a linked-list-like structure or a mechanism for picking another slot if the first slot that matched was occupied by a non-equal key.

Since this adds cost, the more often such collisions happen the slower things become and in the worse case lookup would in fact be O(n) (and slow as O(n) goes, too).

Increasing the size of the internal store will generally improve this though, especially if it is not to a multiple of the previous size (so the operation that reduced the hash code to find an index won't take a bunch of items colliding on the same index and then give them all the same index again). Some mechanisms will increase the internal size before absolutely necessary (while there is some empty space remaining) in certain cases (certain percentage, certain number of collisions with objects that don't have the same full hash code, etc.)

This means that unless the hash codes are very bad (most obviously, if they are in fact all exactly the same), the order of operation stays at O(1).

Comment: Thanks Jon for replying. Let's take Java hashcode() method as an example. This method returns int. Does this mean that the HashMap (that will use this method) will make an array of 2 power 32 entries (4 Giga entries) in RAM . If not so why the return type is int, is seems better to make it byte/short type.

Comment: It'll start off at a smaller size, but get larger as needed. Going for 4billion possible values both gives a large maximum size and also makes it less likely that when modulo down to a smaller size that two items keep colliding each time.

Comment: This seams reasonable, Jon +1